# Getting the name of a script that resize images to its container + other features

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I came accross a website that I really liked for its features.
[Click here to go to the website](http://heydays.no/)

I would like to develop something similar that will be manageable from a wordpress CMS.
I would like to know if I can buy or use a plug-ins/scripts that already take care of all of this:

- Have a grid builder that allow us to define the size of every item (width and height) + order items
- Have the ability to add a background image inside the block
- The background image has to scale proportialy inside the size of its container
- Have the ability to use css class to update the layout (if needed)
- Add the ability to implement different images on hover + caption + style + text + link etc

Any links/exemples/plug-in are more than welcome, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your are searching for what we call it in Germany: "egg-laying, milk-bearing woolly sow". It means as much as: Something like this doesn't exist.

But you can use [gridster](http://gridster.net/) to get around the hard part and add some really easy functions:

```
<div class="gridster">
   <ul>
     <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="CSS Class" class="classname">
<input type="text" placeholder="Content" class="content">
<input type="text" placeholder="Image URL" class="imageurl">
<button class="add">Add</button>
```

And in your script file when your DOM is loaded:

```
//init gridster
 var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');

//get the content
var myDynamicClass=$("input.classname").val();
var myDynamicContent=$("input.content").val();
var myDynamicImage='style="background-image:url('+$("input.imageurl").val()+')  no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;"';

//add a new grid element to gridster
$("button.add").click(function(){
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="'+myDynamicClass+'" '+myDynamicImage+'>'+myDynamicContent+'</li>', 2, 1);
});
```

EDIT:
You can implement a cropping and resizing tool with js on your own. [Here](http://codepen.io/janhommes/full/eaKsA/) is a complete client side solution I did just some days ago. Basically you manipulate it with javascript, load it into a canvas, crop it and after all save the canvas as a image.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very helpful. But, what I'm looking the most is a script to resize/crop images inside its container. It has to work responsively